# Is there a way for logged in user to store the database in their own account in django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project to store my daily expenses.

models.py:

```
class BudgetInfo(models.Model):
    items= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cost= models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    date_added= models.DateField()
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

view.py:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.get_user()
            login(request,user)
            return render (request, 'tasks_notes/index.html')

def additem_view(request):
    name = request.POST['expense_name']    
    expense_cost = request.POST['cost']  
    expense_date = request.POST['expense_date']
    create=BudgetInfo.objects.create(user= request.user,items=name,cost=expense_cost,date_added=expense_date)
    create.save()
    return redirect('app')

def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= RegisterationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('login')
    else: 
        form=RegisterationForm()
    return render(request, 'tasks_notes/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py:

```
class RegisterationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=(
             'username',
             'first_name',
             'last_name',
             'email',
             'password1',
             'password2'
            )
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user=super(RegisterationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email=self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

I want to store the daily expense of each user in its own model. But every instance (even with the same user) is created whenever I am trying to save the data. I want a single instance of the model for each user. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 create=BudgetInfo.objects.create(user=request.user,items=name,cost=expense_cost,date_added=expense_date)
```

Instead of creating each row in the table where you used .create in the above, just update the row by filtering the current user.

```
balance = [str(obj.cost) for obj in BudgetInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)]
```

From the above line you get the current balance of the logged in user.Now, just use .update to update the daily expense without creating a new row for the same user.

```
BudgerInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(cost=int(balance[0]) + expense_cost)
```

The row with the current logged in user gets updated by adding the expense_cost added to the current balance